# PHP - Me sale el error "Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: invalid json token" al recargar la pagina

Tags: php, html

Buenos días con todos y de antemano gracias por leer este post.

Estoy tratado de hacer una web a la cual los usuarios se puedan loguear con su cuenta de `gmail` para poder comentar en la pagina.
La cuestión es que cuando estoy logueado me aparece el nombre del usuario y todo bien hasta allí. pero cuando recargo la pagina me sale ese código de error.

Probé redireccionarlo a otra pagina con `HEADER LOCATION`, cuando redirecciona se soluciona lo del error al recarga la pagina pero ya no me sale el nombre de usuario. Osea como si la variable que quiero imprimir estuviese vacía.

Ese script php lo tengo subido a un **hosting** y les dejo el link para que puedan ver mejor el error.

https://romantex.000webhostapp.com/

Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos y gracias de nuevo.

**Archivo index.php**

```
<?php
$t;
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 
require_once('app/clases/google_auth.php');
require_once('app/init.php'); 

$googleClient = new Google_Client();
$auth = new GoogleAuth($googleClient); 

if($auth->checkRedirectCode()){
    //die($_GET['code']);
    //header('Location: index.php');
   GLOBAL $t;
   $t = $titi; 
    echo $t;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl(); ?>"> Inicia Sesion</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Archivo google_auth.php**

```
<?php
$titi;
class GoogleAuth{

    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Google_Client $googleClient = null){
        $this->client = $googleClient;
        if($this -> client){
            $this -> client ->setClientId('77259071327-0vp6kjmroik970esgn27elkfvcl9abir.apps.googleusercontent.com');
            $this -> client ->setClientSecret('YxcyNRPXe-xg4UTBpD_UQdOs');
            $this -> client ->setRedirectUri('https://romantex.000webhostapp.com/index.php');
            $this -> client ->setScopes('profile');
        }
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(){
        return isset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    public function getAuthUrl(){
        return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    public function checkRedirectCode(){
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $this->setToken($this->client->getAccessToken());
            $payload = $this->getPayload();
            GLOBAL $titi;
            $titi = ($payload['name']);
            //echo $titi;
            //$this->pupu($tu);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

   //public function pupu($mrd){
   //    echo $mrd;
   //}

   public function setToken($token){
       $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
       $this->client->setAccessToken($token);
   }

   public function getPayload(){
       $payload = $this->client->verifyIdToken();
       return $payload;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que no publiques los datos de ***clientId*** y de ***clientSecret***. Saludos

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la recomendación estimado. Si es por lo de la seguridad de la cuenta no tengo problema pues es solo una cuenta de prueba. La verdad es que estoy intentando aprender php por mi cuenta y hoy me encontré con este problema el cual no puedo solucionar :(

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Recomendaría que uses el código [como indica Google en la documentación](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php). Por ejemplo, para manejar el token, ellos indican que se use `json_decode`, como se puede ver en esta línea: `$accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);`

Comment: Buenas tardes A. Cedano. Me podrías decir mas o menos como podría incluirlo en mi código por favor? Gracias de antemano.